# Can be used a lab on a chip device as a nuclear fusion device?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, nuclear-technology, lithography

This is what a lab on a chip is
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab-on-a-chip

I ask if could be used as a nuclear fusion device , that could rise the number of nuclear fusion per atom, knowing that microchannels can mix better substances?

Microchannels could be made by engineering means, like photolithography , already are made microchannels at the size of few micrometers

Microchannels could be working either by light either by small electromagnets

I think that could work because the nanochannels or microchannels could be used one time, as pellets are used in the laser driven nuclear fusion.

Could be used, burnt , and replaced with another pellet like usual pellets are used in the laser driven nuclear fusion.

It's just needed that a continous flow of pellets like this to be used

Notice that i spoke about a microchannel that works either by light either by small electromagnets.

The substances , or in this case of fusion, the ions could be moved by a magnetic field

As far as i know ions could be moved no matter how small a channel could be , by a magnetic field

Laminar flow would not be a problem since the number of molecules involved in fusion would be small

Comment: Hi user38657, welcome to engineering. I think your question - with the current state of the art technological capabilities - is in the realm of science fiction.

Comment: Fusion that has positive net result is very hard. See tokamak reactors and ITER into the difficulties. Fusion for fun is very easy but not helpful, see IEC reactors often called ‚star in a jar‘ fusion reactors made by hobbyists in google images. This is the extent of fusion in modern science.

Comment: Actually, mixing is harder in micro channels because flow is always laminar.

Answer (score 1):

The energies (expressed as temperature) required to get elements to fuse is far above the melting point of all engineering materials. For this reason, all fusion reactors must confine the plasma with magnetic fields that hold the plasma away from the physical walls of the reactor. If the hot plasma were to ever touch the walls, it would burn through them in an instant.